# "How to fix 'malformed URL' in Selenium web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is that I am attempting to scrape the titles of Netflix movies and shows from a website that lists them on 146 different pages, so I made a loop to try and capture data from all the pages, however, when using the loop it makes my URL malformed and I don't know how to fix it.

I have made sure the webdriver part of the code works, meaning if I type in the URL to the driver.get it gives me the information I need, however when using the loop it pops up multiple firefox windows and doesnt put any URL into any of the windows. I also added a time delay to try and see if it was changing the URL before it got used but it still didn't work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
for i in range(1,3):
    URL = "https://flixable.com/?min-rating=0&min-year=1920&max-year=2019&order=date&page={}"
    newURL = URL.format(i)
    print(newURL)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('newURL')
    titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#filterContainer > div > div > p > strong > a')
for post in titles:
    print(post.text)
```

Comment: If that's your actual indentation,  you should indent the second `for` loop. Also initialise your `webdriver` before the first loop, not in it.

Comment: `driver.get('newURL')` you're passing the string `'newURL'` instead of the variable